# Substitute all multi-line and single-line matches in sed

Tags: sed, grep

I would like to replace the same pattern multiple times (`/g`). The pattern can appear in a single line or span several lines (2+).

So, for instance, I'd like to change

```
EXPECT_EQ(50, var1);
EXPECT_EQ(10, 
var2);
EXPECT_EQ(20,
an_expression
_that_takes
_multiple_lines);
```

to something like

```
EXPECT_EQ(var1, 50);
EXPECT_EQ(var2, 
0);

EXPECT_EQ(an_expression
_that_takes
_multiple_lines,
20);
```

The issue is that

```
sed -E 's/EXPECT_EQ\(([0-9]+), (.*)\);/EXPECT_EQ(\2, \1);/g' file.txt
```

will only update the first line in the example since the second match I want has 2 lines.

Is there a way to substitute all match independent of how many lines they have? Something like https://regex101.com/r/QmHCyo/1 but with sed.

Whitespaces or new lines in the result string are of no concern. They can have any format since they are automatically fixed later.

Comment: Since this looks like C++, can't you just define a preprocessing macro: `#define EXPECT_EQ(a,b) EXPECT_EQ((b),(a))`, or via `c++ -D 'EXPECT_EQ(a,b)=EXPECT_EQ((b),(a))' -E file.hpp`

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU sed` stream editor utility with the extended regexes activated `-E` we can perform the manipulation as shown:

```
sed -Ee '
  /^EXPECT_EQ\(.*\);$/!{
    $!N;H;z;x;D
  }
  s/\(([^,]+)(,\s*)(.*)\);$/(\3\2\1);/
' file
```

---

Result:-

```
EXPECT_EQ(var1, 50);
EXPECT_EQ(var2, 
10);
EXPECT_EQ(an_expression
_that_takes
_multiple_lines,
20);
```

Note that we are assuming that the brackets are not nested and the particular function Expect_eq is being modified.

The goal is to accumulate In the pattern space until the brackets balance.
After which we flip the two arguments separated by comma and optional space.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed for `-E` and `-z`:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(\(\s*)([^),]+\S)(\s*,\s*)([^),]+\S)(\s*\))/\1\4\3\2\5/g' file
EXPECT_EQ(var1, 50);
EXPECT_EQ(var2,
10);
EXPECT_EQ(an_expression
_that_takes
_multiple_lines,
20);
```